# Installing rbenv on docker ubuntu/debian

Tags: ruby, docker, rbenv

I want to install rbenv on Docker which seems to work but I can't reload the shell.

```
FROM node:0.10.32-slim

RUN \
      apt-get update \
  &&  apt-get install -y sudo

RUN \
      echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers \
  &&  groupadd r \
  &&  useradd r -m -g r -g sudo

USER r

RUN \
      git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv \
  &&  echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc \
  &&  echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

RUN rbenv # check if it works...
```

When I run this I get:

```
docker build .       

..

Step 5 : RUN rbenv
/bin/sh: 1: rbenv: not found
```

From what I understand, I need to reload the current shell so I can install ruby versions. Not sure if I am on the right track.

Also see:
[Using rbenv with Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884546/using-rbenv-with-docker)

Answer (score 5):

The RUN command executes everything under /bin/sh, thus your bashrc is not evaled at any point.

use this

```
&& export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" \
```

which would append rbenv to /bin/sh's PATH.

Full Dockerfile

```
FROM node:0.10.32-slim

RUN \
      apt-get update \
  &&  apt-get install -y sudo

RUN \
      echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers \
  &&  groupadd r \
  &&  useradd r -m -g r -g sudo

USER r

RUN \
      git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv \
  &&  echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc \
  &&  echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc \
  &&  export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"

RUN rbenv # check if it works...
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how Docker works, but it seems like maybe you're missing a step where you `source ~/.bashrc`, which is preventing you from having the `rbenv` executable in your `PATH`. Try adding that right before your first attempt to run `rbenv` and see if it helps.

You can always solve `PATH` issues by using the absolute path, too. Instead of just `rbenv`, try running `$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv`.

If that works, it indicates that rbenv has installed successfully, and that your `PATH` is not correctly set to include its `bin` directory.

It looks from reading the other question you posted that docker allows you to set your `PATH` via an `ENV PATH` command, like this, for example:

```
ENV PATH $HOME/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

but you should make sure that you include all of the various paths you will need.

Comment: I tried that actually but I get: /bin/sh: 1: source: not found. Weird. Maybe I shouldn't be using the slim version of the library.

Comment: @Rimian, I updated my answer with another suggestion. It's not a durable solution, but it will probably help you get over this speed bump at least.

Comment: Yeah that gets me moving forward, I think. Many thanks!

Comment: @Rimian No problem. I updated again with a solution that may actually be the real solution.