# rbenv: command not found using docker

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, rbenv

i am trying to install ruby 2.7 using `rbenv` on a docker environment, below is the relevant part of my docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2

RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y git-core zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev patch build-essential libpq-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev software-properties-common libffi-dev nodejs yarn tzdata imagemagick postgresql postgresql-contrib && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/HEAD/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
RUN echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN source ~/.bashrc

RUN git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git
RUN PREFIX=/usr/local ./ruby-build/install.sh

RUN rbenv install 2.7.1
RUN gem install bundler
```

this results in following error

```
#13 1.036 /bin/bash: rbenv: command not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/bash -c rbenv install 2.7.1]: exit code: 127
```

any help on how to fix this would be great, thanks.

Comment: `RUN source` does absolutely nothing (and won't work at all in many contexts since `source` isn't a standard Bourne shell command).  I'd suggest avoiding a version manager like `rbenv` and directly installing the Ruby version you need.  Just building an image `FROM ruby:2.7.1` might be enough for your needs.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26879749) to [Installing rbenv on docker ubuntu/debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879600/installing-rbenv-on-docker-ubuntu-debian) might help your immediate needs (remove the unnecessary `source` command and `SHELL` reset but add an `ENV PATH=...` to add the rbenv path) but also see [Is it a bad practice to use version managers like RVM inside docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918837/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-version-managers-like-rvm-inside-docker-containers) (yes).

Comment: hi @DavidMaze, i need to do it using a `ubuntu` image as i want to install rails ultimately.

Comment: You shouldn't need any specific Linux distribution base for that and even the prebuilt `ruby` image should work fine; the various Rails dependencies will be listed out in your application's `Gemfile`.